# Problem with custom hash with unordered_map

Tags: c++, dictionary, hash, unordered-map

I have an unordered_map with elements indexed by a pair(string, enum) and with a custom hasher like this :

```cpp
enum E { A, B, C };

using my_type = std::pair<std::string, E>;

struct _my_type_hasher : std::hash<std::string>, std::unary_function < my_type, size_t >
{
    size_t operator()(const my_type& id) const
    {
        size_t r = std::hash<std::string>::operator()(id.first);
        r *= id.second;
        return r;


        //return std::hash<std::string>()(id.first) ^ std::hash<int>()(id.second);
    }
};

std::unordered_map<my_type, Bar, _my_type_hasher> m_foo;
```

As there is an obvious collision when the value of the enum is A (multiplied by 0), we changed the hasher with the commented line in the operator() of the hasher.

But we found that sometimes, results in our product are different between the two hashers while unordered_map should handle collisions. Each time there was a difference, it meant that there was a problem with our dataset.

But in a c++ point of view, even if datasets used in our products are not good, why there is a behaviour difference between two hashes ??

Thanks a lot !

Comment: what exactly is the problem? Different hashes are different, thats the question?

Comment: As an implementation note, I would advise against inheriting from `std::hash<std::string>`, and depending on what standard you are targeting, also `std::unary_function`

Comment: The problem is that the two versions of hashes produce different results on the application while the unordered_map should manage collisions, so results shall not be different between hash with collisions and hash without collisions !

Comment: what result are different? Please include a [mcve] together with output and expected output

Comment: Unfortunately I can't reproduce it in a small example. It's in a plugin of a big application with some specific data.
It was just to see if someone know one possibility making results different because of the hash method of an unordered_map.